# How do readers of Homer's Odyssey tend to react to Odysseus' raid on the Cicones at Ismaros?

Tags: greek, trojan-war, homer, odysseus

Near the beginning of Book 9, the first incident in Odysseus' account to his Phaeacean hosts of his journey home after the Trojan War.